# MySql selecionar diversas colunas de uma mesma tabela com condições

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso selecionar alguns dados de uma única tabela dependendo do tipo de usuário, por exemplo, um usuário Pessoa Física terá o campo RG e PIS enquanto que um usuário terá o campo Inscrição estadual e nome fantasia.

Eu consigo executar uma *query* semelhante com `LEFT JOIN`, porém todos os campos são selecionados, diferenciando apenas de ter o campo preenchido ou `null`, de acordo com o tipo de usuário. O que desejo é selecionar os campos somente quando o tipo for correspondente, ex.:

- Tipo 1 ou 2: Seleciona os campos comuns;
- Tipo = 1: Seleciona os dados de Pessoa Física (preenchidos ou não);
- Tipo = 2: Seleciona os dados de Pessoa Jurídica (preenchidos ou não);

A *query* que tenho atualmente seria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT
    a.campo_a, a.campo_b, a.campo_c,

    -- Tipo 1
    b.campo_d, b.campo_e, --pode ter mais campos aqui

    -- Tipo 2
    c.campo_f, c.campo_g --pode ter mais campos aqui

FROM tabela AS a
    LEFT JOIN tabela AS b ON a.tipo = 1
    LEFT JOIN tabela AS c ON a.tipo = 2
WHERE a.id = :id
```

Porém, caso eu esteja selecionando tipo 1, ainda assim vejo os campos `campo_f` e `campo_g`, gostaria que eles nem aparecessem, é possível?

Comment: tendo como exemplo pessoa física / jurídica, na mesma tabela você tem 2 colunas, uma para CPF e outra para CNPJ correto ? Tem muitas colunas assim ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Opção: Union (só se for o mesmo tipo de dado)

```
SELECT
    nome, 
    cpf, 
    rg
FROM pessoas where tipo = 1

UNION 

SELECT
    razao,
    cnpj,
    ie
FROM pessoas where tipo = 2;
```

2-Opção: Coalesce (se os campos forem nulos quando de outro tipo)

```
SELECT
Coalesce(nome,razao) as nome,
Coalesce(cpf,cnpj) as documento,
Coalesce(rg,ie) as registro
FROM pessoas;
```

3-Opção: Alterar o banco de dados (Eu faria assim)

Coluna `nome`: compartilharia dados de razão social para pessoas jurídicas, e nome de pessoas físicas.

Coluna `documento`: compartilharia dados de cnpj para pessoas jurídicas, e cpf para pessoas físicas.

Coluna `apelido`: compartilharia nome fantasia para pessoas jurídicas, e apelido para pessoas físicas.

Depois o `SQL` fica limpo, sem problema algum.

```
Select
  nome,
  apelido,
  documento,
  ...
From pessoas;
```

**Edit:**

Considerando que irá carregar PF e PJ em momentos distintos, ou seja, não devem vir no mesmo SELECT, faria pela programação.

```
string sql;
if (pf)
 sql = "select nome, cpf, ... from pessoas;";
else
 sql = "select razao, cnpj, ... from pessoas";

...executa sql;
```

porém, dessa forma você pode ter problemas ao preencher suas variáveis pelo nome das colunas.

Comment: A opção 1 funciona parcialmente, pois dependendo os tipos de dados, o retorno é false. A opção 2 e 3 não se aplicam a minha estrutura atual. Respondendo a sua questão no comentário: a tabela tem foco em cliente PF, com muitos campos relacionados a isso, como rg, PIS, etc.. Alguns campos (2-4) são relacionados a PJ. O que desejo evitar é justamente o carregamento desnecessário no caso de PJ. Mas acho que vou de LEFT JOIN e tratar com o próprio PHP, estou vendo que com o sql não vou conseguir o resultado desejado.

Comment: na questão dos tipos de dados do union, você pode tentar converte-los se possível. E se, são somente 2-4 campos de pessoa jurídica, eu consideraria a alteração da tabela para a opção 3 que postei. Não utilizaria essa opção do LEFT JOIN, me parece desnecessário. Há também a opção de uma função IFF(bool, true, false)

Comment: Pois é, mas o problema não é nem tanto isso. Me preocupa mais o fato de eu ter que carregar 10-15 campos a mais e nulos quando eu estiver carregando um cliente PJ, pois ai sim há diferença. A maioria dos campos são referentes a cliente PF. No caso de usar a opção 3, já faço algo compartilhado, tenho campos como `nome-razao` e `cpf-cnpj`, que já dividem a informação equivalente. Talvez até a segmentação de tabelas, ex.: `cliente`, `cliente_pf` e `cliente_pj`

Comment: bom, estou pensando que deveria ser para carregar pf e pj no mesmo select, se é para quando diferentes tipos, for diferentes comandos, melhor mesmo no php você fazer um condicional

Comment: Pois é, só não sei se carrego todos os campos e posteriormente removo os que forem `null`, ou verifico o tipo para executar um `select` ou outro. Essa query é rodada somente para carregamento de um único cliente e não de uma lista inteira, então o impacto em performance não será problema.

Comment: aí tem que ver como você exibe esses dados, se for dinâmico, utilizaria essa condição dentro do php

Comment: Sim sim, mas valeu pelas dicas! Agora eu entendi por que o UNION não funcionava antes (havia testado com ele).

Answer (score 0):

CASE , algo assim

```
select (case when tipo = 1 then cpf
             when tipo = 2 then cnpj
             else null end) cpf_cnpj, 
...
```

Comment: o problema é que com CASE eu nao consegui utilizar mais de um campo, a nao ser que crie multiplos cases, o que seria inviável. Ai seria melhor manter o left join.

Comment: A opção do UNION do Rovann é viável também;